# Insterting array as parameter to query in node.js mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js

I tried searching for this but most results take me to bulk inserts in Node.js which I don't need atm. To my understanding bulk instert means inserting multiple rows, which i don't need.

I'm trying to use an array of object as a parameter for a query:

```
function saveDomicilio(id_establecimiento, token, order, total){
var order = [{"id":1,"quantity":2},{"id":"3","quantity":"4"}];

console.log("Order" + order);  // logs correctly my order

var new_Domicilio = {
  id_establecimiento: id_establecimiento,
  id_usuario: token,
  orden: order,
  total : total
};

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

if(err) { 
  console.log(err); 
  return; 
}

// make the query

connection.query("INSERT INTO domicilio SET ?", [new_Domicilio], function(err, results) {  
  if(err) { 
    console.log(err); 
    return; 
  }

  console.log("New domicilio created");
  return;

}); // query
}); // pool
};
```

There seems to be a problem with using an array I get the error:

> { [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''{\"id\":1,\"cantidad\":2}', `total` = 300

How am i supposed to do it?

Comment: Don't you call `2 rows`, `multiple rows`?

Comment: No, I don't think so? I just want to insert new_Domicilio to one row

Comment: You have 2 objects in your array, means 2 rows. How can you save it to one row? What is your table structure?

Comment: `order` is a `text` type. I'm trying to save that array in there.

Other parameters which i don't think matter a lot are:
id_establecimiento: int,
id_usuario: int,
total: int

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it in one `row` then don't wrap in with `[]`

try this

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO `domicilio` SET ?", new_Domicilio, function(err, results) {  
  if(err) { 
    console.log(err); 
    return; 
  }
```

Comment: It should work, since it works for me, can you wrap `domicilio` and try again?

Comment: Same mistake I don't know what's wrong, my log says `Orden{"id":3,"cantidad":5},{"id":1,"cantidad":2}`  Doesn't works even wrapping domicilio and removing the []

Comment: Is it `orden` or `order`?

Comment: Orden, I just made a quick translate to make it more 'understandable' I'm using consistently "orden" as variable. I'm not using schemas

Comment: mean `domicilio` table is schemaless ?

Comment: I think so? Not sure what you mean by schema. Domicilio is just a table in a mysql database.